# Convert SQL query to eloquent query with relationship in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, join, group-by, eloquent

I want to convert this SQL query to an eloquent query :

```
SELECT
    round(AVG(rating.reviews), 2) as avg_rating,
    COUNT(excursions.id) as review_total,
    excursions.name
FROM
    reviews
    LEFT JOIN excursions ON reviews.excursion_id = excursions.id GROUP BY excursion_id
```

Anyone can help me?

I've tried this, but I also want to try whether I can use eloquent query

```
DB::table('reviews')
->select(DB::raw("'round'(AVG(rating), 2) as avg_rating"), DB::raw("'COUNT'('excursions.id') as review_total"), 'excursions.name')
->leftJoin('excursions','reviews.excursion_id','=','excursions.id')
->groupBy('excursion_id')
->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have set up the proper relationships between your `Review` and `Excursion` models, you can convert the SQL query to an Eloquent query with the following code:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Review;

$reviews = Review::leftJoin('excursions', 'reviews.excursion_id', '=', 'excursions.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('ROUND(AVG(rating.reviews), 2) AS avg_rating'))
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(excursions.id) as review_total')
    ->addSelect('excursions.name')
    ->groupBy('excursion_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It's not converted to eloquent relations.. The same as query builder.. There is no eloquent relations